# Using handlebars helpers to detect if two dates match

Tags: node.js

So a bit of context, I have a website which as events on it. Some events last one day, others more than one. In order to show what events I have upcoming, I sort through the collection using mongodb and compare the end date with the date today. However at the moment I have both dates showing which looks horrible if the dates match, the below handblebars helper is meant to detect if two dates are the same. However at the moment it doesn't seem to be working.

helper

```
handlebars.registerHelper('ifEquals', function(arg1, arg2, options) {
    return (arg1 == arg2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
});
```

The hbs page.

```
<h4>{{#ifEquals startDate endDate}}the same date{{else}}it's different{{/ifEquals}}</h4>
```

Data being passed that should work but doesn't

```
arg1 2019-08-23T23:17:52.000Z
arg2 2019-08-23T23:17:52.000Z
```

Dates that don't match, these are detected as different but i don't think that's  a positive the function/data is correct

```
arg1 2019-08-24T23:00:00.000Z
arg2 2019-08-27T12:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because javascript compare dates by object equality so you have to check if date one time stamp is equal date to be the below code :

```
handlebars.registerHelper('ifEquals', function(arg1, arg2, options) {
    return (arg1.getTime() == arg2.getTime()) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
});
```

for more exambles :

```
var a = new Date('2019-08-23T23:17:52.000Z')
var b = new Date('2019-08-23T23:17:52.000Z')

a == b // return false 
a.getTime() == b.getTime() // return true 

var a = new Date('2019-08-23T23:17:52.000Z')
var b = a

a == b // return true  
a.getTime() == b.getTime() // return true
```